# Cordova iOS App Xcode - Error - Ran out of executable memory while allocating 128 bytes

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

When I build my Cordova iOS App in Xcode I get this output error?!

```
Ran out of executable memory while allocating 128 bytes
```

Anyone know how to fix this?!